# Java cannot find symbol for my own class

Tags: java

I know that this has been asked a million times before but I still can't figure out a solution to my problem based on the previous solutions. Most of the questions I saw involved classes spawning multiple files, and environment variables and weird stuff like that that a beginner like myself can't comprehend.

I have a very simple test setup to try to understand the problem.

```
class Class1{
}

public class testClasses{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print(Class1);
    }
}
```

(obviously in a file called `testClasses.java`).

It gives me an error, saying `cannot find symbol` referring to `Class1`. What on earth is going on in Java, that makes it unable to recognize `Class1`?

Comment: `Class1` is nothing. Currently it thinks it needs to refer to a variable named `Class1`, you probably want `Class1.class` or `new Class1()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler thinks that `Class1` is a variable, that you have not declared. What you want is propably

```
System.out.println(Class1.class);
```

or

```
System.out.println(new Class());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you actually meant:

```
System.out.print(new Class1());
```

In order to have this working (printing something human-readable), you need to override the `toString()` method in your `Class1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `Class1` is not a symbol, or a variable. It is the name of a class. A reference to that class. When you go to print it out; the `System.out.println` method takes an object. Which you do not have.

You could try `System.out.println(new Class1())` if that's what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

Only `Class1` does not mean anything to `JVM`, So you can either use as

```
System.out.println(Class1.class);
```

or

```
System.out.println(new Class());
```